# Rails mark an order order as complete. This order is made from a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Hello there im new to rails so i really appreciate any help on the matter.

Im looking for a way to mark a order as complete. A example of this is i have a list of orders that admins can view with the following code.

```
.row
  .col-md-8
    - for order in @order
      %h2
        = order.user.name
      .orderpanel
        .clientarea
          Client name:
          = order.user.name
          %br
          Client email:
          = order.user.email
          %br
          Client address ... -->:
          %br
          = order.user.address_line_1
          %br
          = order.user.address_line_2
          %br
          = order.user.postcode
          %br
          = order.user.city
          %br
          = order.user.country
        .delivarea
          %br
          delivery_name:
          = order.delivery_name
          %br
          company_name:
          = order.company_name
          %br
          delivery_address1:
          = order.delivery_address1
          %br
          delivery_address2:
          = order.delivery_address2
          %br
          delivery_address3:
          = order.delivery_address3
          %br
          delivery_city:
          = order.delivery_city
          %br
          delivery_postcode:
          = order.delivery_postcode
          %br
          phone:
          = order.phone
          %br
          package_contents:
          = order.package_contents
          %br
          description_content:
          = order.description_content
          %br
          contents_value:
          = order.contents_value
          %br
          cf_reference:
          = order.id
          CR
          %br
          reference_number:
          = order.reference_number
        .tac
          restricted_items:
          = order.restricted_items
          %br
          terms_conditions:
          = order.terms_conditions
          %br
          insurance:
          = order.insurance
          = order.id
  .col-md-4.sidebar
    = paginate @order
```

Is there some way of selecting a order by its name or id. Then adding a new completed field thew a migration to orders. By clicking a button setting that value to true. Sorry im new to rails and i wonder if there is a way to do this.

Here is my orders controller:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  def create
    @order = current_user.orders.new(order_params)
    @order.email = current_user.email
    @order.name = current_user.name
    @order.address_line_1 = current_user.address_line_1
    @order.address_line_2 = current_user.address_line_2
    @order.postcode = current_user.postcode
    @order.city = current_user.city
    @order.country = current_user.country
    if @order.save
      redirect_to dconfirmation_path
    end
  end

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).
      permit(
        :email,
        :delivery_name,
        :company_name,
        :delivery_address1,
        :delivery_address2,
        :delivery_address3,
        :delivery_city,
        :delivery_postcode,
        :delivery_country,
        :phone,
        :package_contents,
        :description_content,
        :restricted_items,
        :terms_conditions,
        :insurance,
        :contents_value,
        :cf_reference,
        :reference_number
        )
  end
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def confirmation
  end

end
```

Thank you for your help i will be viewing this post regularly. If anyone can help or look at it i really appreciate your time. I will provide any more details you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a migration to add :complete to `Order`, i.e.

```
rails g migration add_complete_to_order
```

Then in the generated migration file:

```
add_column :orders, :complete, :boolean, default: false
```

Then in `order.rb` you can add a method:

```
def complete!
  update(complete: true)
end
```

Which you can call at any time in the process when you want to mark an order as complete

You can also use a `button_to` to create your button. [http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to ]

```
<%= button_to "Mark as complete", { action: "complete", id: @order.id } %>
```

Or instead of the hash, you can use the full path, something like `complete_order_path(@order)` (check the path by running `rake routes`.

But then you will need to either add a new route and action in your orders controller. For example:

```
resources :orders do
  post "complete", to: "orders#complete", on: :member
end
```

Which should give you a url structure of `orders/:order_id/complete`
Then in your `OrdersController`:

```
def complete
  order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
  order.complete!
  # handle response
end
```

But this is just one example of how you can do that

If you have a collection of orders, you will need to loop through each one and define a button for each order. For example:

```
- @orders.each do |order|
 = button_to "#{order.name}: mark as complete", complete_order_path(order)
```

Comment: How would i turn the method complete into a button for a specific order. say order id 1. ps. Thank you for your time in this matter it means the world to me.

Comment: Like is there any way to make a form of some kind were you can select which order to edit. Then apply this method. So select order id 2 and mark as completed is what i mean.

Comment: Hi so i did what you said. Thanks for that but, i need to put the complete! method in the model correct ?. Also i need to be able to select a order in the view to mark as complete any idea how.

Comment: `#complete!` goes in the `Order` model, yes correct, and you can place the `button_to` where ever you like, for example on the orders index view or the order show view

Comment: Hi there, appreciate it could you perhaps give me a example. I cant get it to work, i know im being stupid.

Comment: Im getting a no routes match error. No route matches {:action=>"complete", :controller=>"dashboard", :name=>"Order"}

I put it both in orders controller and dashboard controller. Nothing seems to fix it any idea ?

Comment: What do you get when you run `rake routes | grep complete`

Comment: The error is undefined method `id' for #<Order::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fda70012208> When i use the @order.id for button to.

Comment: As I said in http://stackoverflow.com/a/31406976/1471763, you can use: `= button_to "Mark as complete", complete_order_path(@order)`

Comment: Why is `@order` an `ActiveRecord_Relation`? It should just be an `ActiveRecord` object. How and where do you define `@order`?

Comment: Also, your controller action needs to change to use `params[:order_id]` rather than just `params[:id]` as you can see in the `routes` output

Comment: If i use that then i get undefined method `complete_order_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fda703224e8>:0x007fda706ae6e8>

Im a little confused by your second question about activerecord relation. The order is made by a form. with a basic save function above. Its displayed in the controllers

Comment: order_complete POST   /orders/:order_id/complete(.:format) orders#complete
Thats the output from the rake task

Comment: Hi there sorry for the confession here is a screen grab of the error here.
http://i.gyazo.com/6b3aecc2253d664cc28dbc769fb4df0c.png 

You really seem to know what you are doing and would greatly appreciate your imput.

Comment: Where is `@order` defined for that view?

Comment: dadmin is the page.
dashboard_controller.rb has the following that defines the orders.
http://i.gyazo.com/88009c59c552d0886ec27dc560124a92.png

Comment: Actually looking at `Dashboard#dadmin` action, it has: `@order = Order.order("name").page(params[:page]).per(1)`. That is `ActiveRecord::Relation` object and for clarity should be renamed to `@orders`, because it is a collection of orders. For each one of those orders, you can then define the `button_to`

Comment: This is the section that counts
  
`  def dadmin
    (current_user.nil?) ? redirect_to(root_path) : (redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?)
    # @order = Order.all
    @order = Order.order("name").page(params[:page]).per(1)
  end
  `

Comment: So i tryed what i think you are saying. = button_to "Mark as complete", { action: "complete", id: @orders.id } But that calls a nill class error: 

undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass