# Rails button_to No route matches {:action=>"complete", :controller=>"dashboard", :name=>"Order"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Please help i have tried my best. I really need your help.

So im trying to make a mark order as complete. Now it all works up to the button to mark order as complete. I ran a migration to add.

```
class AddCompleteToOrder < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :orders, :complete, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

Then i added a method the order.rb of

```
def complete!
  update(complete: true)
end
```

Then routes.rb

```
resources :orders do
  post "complete", to: "orders#complete", on: :member
end
```

Then this is the button

```
= button_to "Mark as complete", { action: "complete", id: @order.id }
```

But i dont have a @order.id
but a order does have a @order.name so i changed it to

```
= button_to "Mark as complete", { action: "complete", name: @order.name }
```

But then i get the error:

ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Dashboard#dadmin
Showing /Users/jacksharville/Desktop/dancer/app/views/dashboard/dadmin.html.haml where line #87 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"complete", :controller=>"dashboard", :name=>"Order"}

Extracted source (around line #87):
85
86
87

```
= link_to "Back to Dashboard", :back, :class => 'btn-danger btn'

= button_to "Mark as complete", { action: "complete", name: @order.name }
```

So clearly im doing the routes.rb wrong but i cant fix it. Please help. Any help greatly appreciated.

routes.rb (full file)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  get 'home/index'
  root 'home#index'
  #pages
  get '/why' => 'pages#why'
  get '/trak' => 'pages#trak'
  get '/contact' => 'pages#contact'
  get '/mydms' => 'pages#mydms'
  get '/air' => 'pages#air'
  get '/ocean' => 'pages#ocean'
  get '/road' => 'pages#road'
  get '/courier' => 'pages#courier'
  get 'fulfilment' => 'pages#fulfilment'
  get 'express' => 'pages#express'

  resources :dashboard
  get 'dadmin' => 'dashboard#dadmin'
  get 'myorders' => 'dashboard#myorders'
  get 'label' => 'dashboard#label'
  resources "contacts", only: [:new, :create]

  devise_for :users
  as :user do
    get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'
    put 'users' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'
  end

  resources "orders"
  get "/confirm" => "confirmations#show"
  get 'dconfirmation' => 'orders#confirmation'

  resources :orders do
    post "complete", to: "orders#complete", on: :member
  end
end
```

orders_controller.rb

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  def create
    @order = current_user.orders.new(order_params)
    @order.email = current_user.email
    @order.name = current_user.name
    @order.address_line_1 = current_user.address_line_1
    @order.address_line_2 = current_user.address_line_2
    @order.postcode = current_user.postcode
    @order.city = current_user.city
    @order.country = current_user.country
    if @order.save
      redirect_to dconfirmation_path
    end
  end

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).
      permit(
        :email,
        :delivery_name,
        :company_name,
        :delivery_address1,
        :delivery_address2,
        :delivery_address3,
        :delivery_city,
        :delivery_postcode,
        :delivery_country,
        :phone,
        :package_contents,
        :description_content,
        :restricted_items,
        :terms_conditions,
        :insurance,
        :contents_value,
        :cf_reference,
        :reference_number
        )
  end
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def confirmation
  end

  def complete!
    order = Order.find(params[:id])
    order.complete!
    # handle response
  end

end
```

dashboard_controller.rb

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
  end

  def admindashboard
    (current_user.nil?) ? redirect_to(root_path) : (redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?)
  end

  def adminuser
    (current_user.nil?) ? redirect_to(root_path) : (redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?)
  end

  def dadmin
    (current_user.nil?) ? redirect_to(root_path) : (redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?)
    # @order = Order.all
    @order = Order.order("name").page(params[:page]).per(1)
  end

  def myorders
    @order = current_user.orders.order("name").page(params[:page]).per(1)
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def label
    @order = current_user.orders.order("name").page(params[:page]).per(1)
  end

  def complete!
    order = Order.find(params[:id])
    order.complete!
    # handle response
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify this additional option in the `button_to` tag `:controller => "order"`, but the proper way to use `button_to` tag is to not create a separate hash for options. Instead use it as a `button_to("Mark as complete", controller: "order", action: "complete", name: @order.name)`

Comment: Thanks for your responce. I still get the same error. No route matches {:action=>"complete", :controller=>"order", :name=>"Order"}
I will edit post above to add full routes file. I think it might be there warning its a mess.

Comment: I have now added those. Thank you for you time.

Comment: You have defined action `complete!` but you are calling action `complete` without the exclamation mark!.

Comment: That does not change anything if i change it to complete for both which i now have same error. It does not take ! into account

Comment: Its like the routes.rb is just not using it at all. I can delete it i get the same error.

Comment: `complete!` is defined on the `Order` class, where the second `complete` is a controller action

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  button_to "Mark as complete", { controller: "orders", action: "complete", name: @order.name },  {method: :post}
```

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"complete", :controller=>"orders", :name=>"Order"}

same error i have added all controllers and route file i appreciate your time spent answering thank you.

Comment: you need to remove 'on: :member' from the routes file here: post "complete", to: "orders#complete", because member routes expects id always. make your comment action as collecition

Comment: If i just delete on member same issue. Same error nothing changes

Comment: Its like the routes.rb is just not using it at all. I can delete it i get the same error.

Comment: how about do this   resources :orders do
  collection do
    post "complete"
  end
end
then do bundle exec rake routes and check route for complete action and use that along with name as parameter.

Comment: these are the relivent rake routes.  http://i.gyazo.com/47229891c510c274f150ca728ed427f4.png

Comment: you see the orders#complete is expecting order_id in it as url which means that it is considering this route as member route. have you used on: :collection

Comment: So how do i fix this can i add a id for each order that is unique for every order ?

Comment: if i change it to id then i get the error undefined method `id'

Comment: id is always unique and they are auto generated in rails for each model. 
order should have id. but if your order dont have id, make collection routes. see point  2.10.2 Adding Collection Routes on this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html. collection dont make id compulsory

Answer (score 0):

This link can help: [Routing Error - No route matches when using button_to with custom action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650213/routing-error-no-route-matches-when-using-button-to-with-custom-action)

rake routes give me:

```
complete_order POST   /order/:id/complete(.:format) orders#complete
```

Comment: This is not related to the question because im updating something with button to i cant just link_to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `complete` action from `DashboardsController` to `OrdersController`, which is where it is defined in the routes file.

Also, you can probably use:

```
= button_to "Mark as complete", complete_order_path(@order)
```

The controller action is looking for `params[:order_id]` so it can find the right order. I am not sure how orders are defined in your view, but you will need to pass an order object to the path.

If by any chance you defined a `to_param` method in `Order` class, which defines order's name rather than id as params, you will need to update the `complete` action to look for an order by name.

But my guess is that it is the default `id`. So passing the order object to the path should work.